# How to Parse CSV Data When Data Contains Commas

Tags: c#, csv

I'm currently working on a CSV file parser in C#, and have found that when a file is parsed, incorrect data is being stored in the output file. Below is my current implementation.

```
private IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> ReadCSVFileContents(string FilePath, Config.FileOptions fileOptions)
    {
        List<IDictionary<String, object>> data = new List<IDictionary<String, Object>>();
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(FilePath))
        {
            var headerLine = reader.ReadLine();
            var headers = headerLine.Split(",");

            while(!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(",").Cast<Object>();
                var row = headers.Zip(values, (k, v) => new { k, v }).ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);

                row.Add("filename", FilePath);
                data.Add(row);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

I know the error stems from the line calling `line.Split(',')` but am unsure as to what to do as some columns contain data as follows.

| Name | Address |
| --- | --- |
| R.S.A, testData | 123 Street, etc. |

If anyone knows how I could correctly parse this information, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use a dedicated library such as CsvHelper.IO that handles these things (and multiline cells, etc.) for you.

Comment: your csv file has to be created correctly in the first place - check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values
In my experience, Split is not the way to go, you will need to parse the whole string taking quotes into account.  quotes also have to be escaped correctly, as per the standard.

Comment: Has your csv got fields containing commas that are enclosed by quotes?  packages such as excel should do that for you.